# R: writing (vectors) datas in separate cells

Tags: r, csv

I've got a problem with writing output datas. I made an instruction like this:

```
myfiles <- list.files("D:/dolnyslask/2011/after", pattern=".csv")
for (j in 1:length(myfiles)) {
  thisfile <- read.csv(myfiles[j], header = T, sep=";", na.string="NA", comment.char="")
  for (i in thisfile) {
    x = sd(i, na.rm=T)
    y = length (na.omit(i))
    if (y == 0) {
      cat(paste(rep(c("-"),11)), file=myfiles[j], append=T, sep="\t")
      cat(paste(length(na.omit(i))), file=myfiles[j], append=T, sep="\n")     
    } else if (is.na(x) || x == 0) {
      cat(paste(format(min(i, na.rm=T)), format(mean(i, na.rm=T)), format(max(i, na.rm=T)), format(median(i, na.rm=T)), format(sd(i, na.rm=T)), format(mean(i, na.rm=T)), format(mean(i, na.rm=T)), format(mean(i, na.rm=T) - mean(i, na.rm=T)), format(mean(i, na.rm=T) - mean(i, na.rm=T)), format((mean(i, na.rm=T) - mean(i, na.rm=T))/median(i, na.rm=T)), format((mean(i, na.rm=T) - mean(i, na.rm=T))/median(i, na.rm=T)), digits=5), file=myfiles[j], append=T, sep="\t")
      cat(paste(length(na.omit(i))), file=myfiles[j], append=T, sep="\n")
    } else { 
      cat(paste(format(min(i, na.rm=T)), format(mean(i, na.rm=T)), format(max(i, na.rm=T)), format(median(i, na.rm=T)), format(sd(i, na.rm=T)), format(t.test(na.omit(i), conf.level=0.90)$conf.int), format(t.test(na.omit(i), conf.level=0.90)$conf.int - mean(i, na.rm=T)), format((t.test(na.omit(i), conf.level=0.90)$conf.int - mean(i, na.rm=T))/median(i, na.rm=T)), digits=5), file=myfiles[j], append=T, sep="\t")
      cat(paste(length(na.omit(i))), file=myfiles[j], append=T, sep="\n")
    }
  }
}
```

My csv files looks like this:

```
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  2   NA  NA  12.1    NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  4   NA  NA  10  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  12.1    NA  NA  8.5 NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  14.8    NA  NA  6   NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  15  NA  NA  7.4 NA
```

R returns me a good results but only in one cell (in csv file) - but I need every one in separated columns. I tried to change kinds on "sep"  but it didn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: Instead of all that `cat`ting, why don't you just assign each value to a separate data.frame column and then use a `write.csv` on that data.frame?

Comment: @Codoremifa I tried to do this, but it didn't works. I've started using R few weeks ago. Maybe I've just done it in wrong way. I don't know....

Comment: `df <- data.frame(meani = mean(i), sdi = sd(i)); write.csv(df,'df.csv')`

Comment: but how to write data.frame for this part when I need have "-"?

Comment: I tried to to do this, but R still writes my datas in one cell;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, assigning each value a data.frame column and then write.csv should work:

```
df <- data.frame(meani = mean(i), sdi = sd(i))
write.csv(df,'df.csv')
```

But reading again maybe you forgot to specify, which kind of separation do you want to read when you open the file. And I would recommend to use `sep="\t"` to create a [tab-delimited](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-data.html) file and open it.

Comment: R still write my table in first cell of the line...:(

Comment: Did you change the `sep="\t"` or read it with comma and tab delimited or whatever options do you have to read from an `.csv` file?
Because if it is not this I don't know what can be done. (But maybe if you provide us with the `dput()` of the thisfile I can play a little bit with it.)

Comment: Ok. I was so stupid... I changed sep="/t" --> it should be sep=";" of course... And firstly all files only need to be open by another programme, and then, when I open them in f.eg. excel I've got all of datas in different cells! I'm sorry 'cuz of this guestion but I thought it was my error in writing commands...

Comment: I am not sure that opening them with another program help but if this answer helped or you want to close the question you can mark my answer as useful for you. Best, Llopis